# Making a game, I can't import a background image or sprite

Tags: python, image, background, insert, pygame

I'm a new programmer, trying to make a platformer-combat 2D scroller game and I have already created my background and a character sprite, but I'm trying to `blit` them into my code, but I get an error saying that

> The first argument needs to be `pygame.Surface()`

When I do this, it then tells me

> ValueError: size needs to be (int width, int height)

I've looked at quite a few questions about this, tried a bunch of things, and nothing works. Please help.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

global X, Y, gameBackground
bg = [pygame.image.load("pygame/gameBackground.png")]
char = [pygame.image.load("pygame/characterStandingRight.png")]
#I have my .png files in a folder named "pygame" inside of my general program folder
windowWidth = 1366
windowHeight = 697
Width = 40
Height = 64
X = 5
Y = windowHeight - (Height + 5)
tick = 30
run = True

def redrawGameWindow():
    window.blit(pygame.Surface(bg), (0, 0)) #draws Window Background
    window.blit(pygame.Surface(char), (X, Y)) #draws Character Sprite
    pygame.display.update()
#above is where I have my errors of "pygame.Surface" and "(int width, int height)"

window = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(tick)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    #other game code which controls character movement functions
    redrawGameWindow()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by `pygame.Surface(bg)` respectively `bygame.Surface(char)`, where `bg` and `char` are lists of objects. There is no constructor of a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) by another Surface or even a list of Surface objects.

Note you've a list of backgrounds and a list of characters

> ```py
> bg   = [ pygame.image.load("pygame/gameBackground.png") ]
> char = [ pygame.image.load("pygame/characterStandingRight.png") ]
> ```

To access an object in a list you've to use the index operator (e.g. `char[0]`). `bg[0]` and `char[0]` are [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) objects and can be used directly in the method [`blit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit). e.g.:

```py
def redrawGameWindow():
    window.blit(bg[0], (0, 0))
    window.blit(char[0], (X, Y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

If you need just a single [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) you would have to skip the `square brackets` (e.g. `bg = pygame.image.load("pygame/gameBackground.png")`).

```py
bg   = pygame.image.load("pygame/gameBackground.png")
char = pygame.image.load("pygame/characterStandingRight.png")
```

```
def redrawGameWindow():
    window.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    window.blit(char, (X, Y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are putting the list into blit, which produces an error. It should be:

```
window.blit(bg[0], (0, 0)) #draws Window Background
```